# Read deleted users from Active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

Is it possible to read deleted users from Active directory?

Simple and short question.
I want read this info with C# UserPrincipal, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can search for deleted users using `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher`. If it's really trivial for you to get the underlying object as `UserPrincipal` you can `cast` `user` object as `UserPrincipal`.

```
public static void searchDeletedUsers()
{
   using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://yourldappath.com"))
   {
      using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry))
      {
         searcher.Filter = "(&(isDeleted=TRUE)(objectclass=user))";
         searcher.Tombstone = true;
         var users = searcher.FindAll();
         foreach(var user in users)
         {
            //user will contain the deleted user object
         }
      }
   }
}
```